# How I get the values in .phtml and pass them to Block

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I’m trying to pass values between textbox in `template/report/grid.phtml` and `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid`
I know how to view values in .phtml file but how I get the values entered by user from `phtml` widget and use it in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid`

Comment: **HI. I wish you won't use bold like that.**

Comment: That's the wrong way to do things. If you have the value in the view then is has already been passed from the Block.
Can you give a specific example?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in that way, as you described it.

For example when user enter something in form on *.phtml page, usually you submit him to some Controller Action. Then you reload a page and deliver user to other (or same) page.

If you want deliver him to same page and pass new parameters to your Block, read this answer, its quite good explaining that

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006908/1831858