# Magento: How to pass a variable from block to a Model

Tags: magento

I am using an extension where I need to pass the variable is moving from block class back to model, I have used session it works sometime but not uniformly,
Is there any other way to pass it,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you use that model in the block in question? Can you give an example? Some code maybe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using Magento’s Registry Pattern

The three registry methods are

```
Mage::register   
Mage::unregister   
Mage::registry
```

The register method is how you set a global-like variable.

```
Mage::register('some_name', $var);
```

Then, later in the request execution, (from any method), you can fetch your variable back out

```
$my_var = Mage::registry('some_name');
```

Finally, if you want to make you variable unavailable, you can use the unregister method to remove it from the registry.

```
Mage::unregister('some_name');
```

[Source](http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial)

Comment: Its sort of coupon code restriction, where the extension is asking the user to input points and based on the calculation, passing the value back to the model. I have tried core/session also but that does work only once the initial value is passed. The session perhaps is not able to set the initial value, its complex at least for me

Comment: Just Try it in the Magento’s Registry Pattern method as said above

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response. When I try to use registry from Model to use in block it is working fine, however if I try and process the value back to model through registry it does not. May be I have gotn a bit confused. But Anyways thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: Hey , why dont you try out a combination as said by @Fantus , and do check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006183/magento-passing-data-between-a-controller-and-a-block ,let me try and prompt you back

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the Model as a singleton, you can try this:

```
 Mage::getSingleton('yourmodule/yourmodel')->setStuff('xxxx');
```

and later

```
 Mage::getSingleton('yourmodule/yourmodel')->getStuff();
```

if you don't know what singletons are you should maybe try the registry approach from epynic to prevent problems.