# How to get product ID in magento inside head section?

Tags: php, magento

Id like to make this work inside themeName/template/page/html/head.phtml

```
<?php echo $_product->getId()
```

I'm trying to add a script in head section and it requires productID, but it only works inside catalog/product.

Is there a way to make it work in head section?

Comment: have you got any product product property?like sku,name attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')){
   echo $_product->getId()
}
```

See [Magento - Passing data between a controller and a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006183/magento-passing-data-between-a-controller-and-a-block)